# Xcode - why didn't this show a warning?

Tags: iphone, xcode, compiler-warnings

I've got a class I wrote earlier in the year, pre 3.0, that implemented the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocol. In it, I implemented the imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo: method, which is deprecated in the 3.0 SDK.

The thing is, I noticed this just by cruising through the documentation, and not from a compiler warning. I was seeing other deprecation warnings (for things like TableViewCell.text) but not this one. Is there a setting or something that I need to have enabled, as I'm wondering now if there are other deprecations that I'm missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No warning is shown because Xcode only warns you about deprecation when you either invoke a deprecated method or access a deprecated property (I'm not sure how deprecated classes are handled).

Neither of the following results in an warning:

1. Overriding a deprecated method of a parent class
2. Implementing a deprecated method of a protocol

If you think about it, this makes some amount of sense. When that deprecated method is eventually removed, it would be perfectly fine for you to name one of your own methods that.

Answer (score 1):

Does anything log to the console when that function is called? I've seen deprecation warnings of that type.